# Is it possible to put generator expressions into cache variables?

Tags: variables, cmake, generator-expression

Say a library (that I don't own) calls

```
include_directories(${SOME_CACHED_DIR})
```

with `SOME_CACHED_DIR` as a cache var, can I then somehow predeclare `SOME_CACHED_DIR` in the parent project like this:

```
    set(SOME_CACHED_DIR CACHE STRING
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${otherlib_BINARY_DIR}>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${otherlib_INSTALL_DIR}>
    )
```

So that I could differentiate out the directories for the build and install tree picked up by `include_directories`? I tried to print out the resulting var using

```
    file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/genexpr.txt CONTENT ${SOME_CACHED_DIR})
```

But it always prints `SOME_CACHED_DIR-NOTFOUND`.

**EDIT**: Corrected spelling mistake

Comment: `SOME_CACHED_DIRCACHE` != `SOME_CACHED_DIR`

Comment: It is very easy to introduce an unintended error into the generator expression. Please, be **precise** when prepare [mcve] for them. Currently, your names of variable(s) `SOME_CACHED_DIRCACHE` and `SOME_CACHED_DIR` are quite confusing. And if instead of `SOME_CACHED_DIRCACHE` you mean two words `SOME_CACHED_DIR CACHE`, then your `set` command has wrong format: value of the CACHE variable should be specified **before** the CACHE keyword, not after it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, yes it was typo. And I did indeed put the value the wrong way around. I changed that and updated my lib to master branch because I saw it doesn't provide a proper install interface in the lts. Now I at least get through configuration and generation phase.